# How can I create a merge base in Git?

Tags: git

I have two branches, one `local` and `remote`.

The `local` was developed in isolation, and `remote` was fetched later.
Now I want to merge them, but they don't have a merge base (no common ancestry). Is there a way I can 'manually' create a merge base? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can 'manually' create a merge base?

Yes you can.
You can `cherry-pick` all the commits from one branch to another with the commit range `..`.

```
git cherry-pick <first commit>..<last-commtit>
```

Git will inform you that those 2 branches are not related.
[image]

Here we will use cherry-pick so the history will be combined and you can see that the new branch contain the history of the orphan branch as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no, but you don't need to".  Older versions of Git allowed `git merge` on unrelated histories.  This is more often a mistake than an intended act, so the newest versions of Git now refuse it by default.  If it's *not* a mistake, though, simply add `--allow-unrelated-histories` to the command, and Git will behave the way it used to.